# git push が通らなくなった

Tags: linux, git, network

##### 環境情報

問題のマシン
Thinkpad x270
OS: Alter Linux x86_64

後述のsshキーに関するテストに使用したマシン

- Thinkpad x230i / kali linux
- Thinkcentre M710q Tiny / windows10

#### 症状

GitHubからクローンしたリポジトリに対して、pullはできるがpushができません。
commitまではできます。（ローカル）
空ファイル１つでもpushできないので、ファイルサイズの問題ではないはずです。

#### ゴール

alter機からGitHub上のリモートリポジトリに`git push`を通すこと

#### 試したこと

1. ポストするバッファサイズの編集は300MBまで試しました。
2. 別階層に改めてclone、もともとのローカルリポジトリにあるpushできていない差分を上書きしてpush
3. ssh-addの確認
   ssh-add -l したときに以下のログ出力。ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_xxxとした時も同様

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

4.ufwの確認
ufwをデフォルト設定で起動するとsshが遮断されるとのこと。
テザリングスマホでコミット成功している時点のufwの状態は以下

```
 systemctl status ufw
● ufw.service - CLI Netfilter Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ufw.service; disabled; vendor prese>
     Active: active (exited) since Thu 2022-06-09 12:59:23 JST; 4 days ago
   Main PID: 254 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 9ms

 6月 09 12:59:23 XXX ufw-init[258]: Skip starting firewall: ufw (no>
 6月 09 12:59:23 XXX systemd[1]: Starting CLI Netfilter Manager...
 6月 09 12:59:23 XXX systemd[1]: Finished CLI Netfilter Manager.
```

#### pushできなくなった時期の心当たりとなる操作

1. 個人アクセストークンの更新
2. ufwの有効化

#### push時のログ

```
Enumerating objects: 102, done.
Counting objects: 100% (75/75), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (43/43), done.
Writing objects: 100% (48/48), 4.88 KiB | 555.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 48 (delta 15), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

#### コメントを受けて新たに試したこと

1. alter機でssh接続確認。失敗
   →鍵再生成、github登録しなおした後、sshコマンドたたいた段階で問題。
   keitaro-soさん添付のURLでいうところのRSAのフィンガープリント確認要求が来る段階でsshコマンドに帰るメッセージなし。
   端末固有の問題か、鍵の問題かを以下２で確認
2. alter機で生成したsshキーをwindows10機とkali機に設置、ssh接続試行
   → kali機では同様にメッセージ返らず。
   → windows10機で以下ログ。公開鍵の権限問題かOSの問題かと。

```
ssh git@github.com
The authenticity of host 'github.com (13.114.40.48)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,13.114.40.48' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

3. Windows10機でpush成功している時に使用しているssh鍵をalter機 /home/(user_name)下に移送してssh接続テスト、pushテスト
   →sshコマンド入力後、メッセージ表示なし。
   →push時のログと同じエラーメッセージ表示。push失敗。

##### 試してpush成功したこと

自室用無線LAN→スマホのテザリングに切り替え。push成功
ただ、自室用無線LANにつないでpushしたい。
ちなみに、スマホはキャリアの回線ではなく、自室用無線LANに接続して、テザリングしてる。

Comment: 参考: [Github - unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66366582)

Comment: `the remote end hung up unexpectedly` ということでpush先に問題がありそうですが、push先はGitHubやGitLabのようなホスティングサービスですか？

Comment: はい、githubです。他端末(Windows10)では正常にpushできるので、push先に問題があるとすれば個人アクセストークンと考えます。alter機とWindows機ではトークンを分けています。

Comment: そもそもその端末でgithubに接続できますか？[SSH接続をテストする](https://docs.github.com/ja/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection)も接続できない場合、同じ鍵を別の端末にインストールして接続できるか試してみてください。鍵の問題なのか端末の問題なのかが区別できます。

Comment: keitaro_soさん
指摘いただいた内容でテストし、結果を記しました。ありがとうございます。
まだ目的は達していないです。

Comment: windows機でも同じ鍵が使えないのであれば鍵の問題かなと思います。ちなみにwindowsでつながる鍵をalter機にもっていって接続できますか？

Comment: windows10機でpushできていた鍵をalter機 /home/(user_name) 下に持っていき、ssh接続テスト、pushしてみましたが、ログも上記と同じ fatal~で不可でした。